# Ada String to Enumeration Conversion

Tags: string, enums, ada

I would like to cast an existing string to an enum (not read it in as an enum). How can I do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

example:

```
-- type declaration
type Hands is (Left, Right);

-- code body
Hand : Hands;
Hand := Hands'Value("Left"); -- yields `Left`
```

Comment: Dont forget, the 'Value operation will fail if you pass it "lef". you can check if your string is convertable by using 'Image & iterating over the scalar type, if you get a true, then use 'Value to convert it.

Comment: Note that you can put an exception handler around this to catch errors where the string doesn't match a known enumeration name. In the past I've found this very handy for quick-and-dirty user interfaces.

Comment: Seems like a good place for nullable type via discriminants.